# Embed SVG in DIV without padding

Tags: svg

We need to wrap up particular SVG in the particular div without any padding and margin.

Please check this code.

```css
div {
    resize: both;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    padding: 1em;
}

svg,
img {
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Embedded SVG:
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.2.0</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667C25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667,25.305555555555557,-9.888888888888886,25.305555555555557,-9.888888888888886C25.305555555555557,-9.888888888888886,16.166666666666668,-9.888888888888886,16.166666666666668,-9.888888888888886C16.166666666666668,-9.888888888888886,16.166666666666668,-19.02777777777777,16.166666666666668,-19.02777777777777C16.166666666666668,-19.02777777777777,46.5,-19.02777777777777,46.5,-19.02777777777777C46.5,-19.02777777777777,46.5,-9.888888888888886,46.5,-9.888888888888886C46.5,-9.888888888888886,37.75,-9.888888888888886,37.75,-9.888888888888886C37.75,-9.888888888888886,37.75,42.41666666666667,37.75,42.41666666666667C37.75,42.41666666666667,25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667,25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667C25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667,25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667,25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.003,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667C61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667,61.47222222222222,-19.02777777777777,61.47222222222222,-19.02777777777777C61.47222222222222,-19.02777777777777,87.13888888888889,-19.02777777777777,87.13888888888889,-19.02777777777777C87.13888888888889,-19.02777777777777,87.13888888888889,-10.472222222222221,87.13888888888889,-10.472222222222221C87.13888888888889,-10.472222222222221,73.91666666666667,-10.472222222222221,73.91666666666667,-10.472222222222221C73.91666666666667,-10.472222222222221,73.91666666666667,6.250000000000007,73.91666666666667,6.250000000000007C73.91666666666667,6.250000000000007,83.25,6.250000000000007,83.25,6.250000000000007C83.25,6.250000000000007,83.25,15.000000000000004,83.25,15.000000000000004C83.25,15.000000000000004,73.91666666666667,15.000000000000004,73.91666666666667,15.000000000000004C73.91666666666667,15.000000000000004,73.91666666666667,33.861111111111114,73.91666666666667,33.861111111111114C73.91666666666667,33.861111111111114,87.13888888888889,33.861111111111114,87.13888888888889,33.861111111111114C87.13888888888889,33.861111111111114,87.13888888888889,42.41666666666667,87.13888888888889,42.41666666666667C87.13888888888889,42.41666666666667,61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667,61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667C61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667,61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667,61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0013,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M118.58333333333333,43.583333333333336C97.97222222222221,43.97222222222223,100.5,21.80555555555556,100.69444444444444,1.5833333333333357C100.69444444444444,-12.999999999999993,106.72222222222221,-20.388888888888886,118.58333333333333,-20.388888888888886C132.58333333333331,-20.388888888888886,136.66666666666666,-9.888888888888886,135.69444444444443,5.4722222222222285C135.69444444444443,5.4722222222222285,123.44444444444444,5.4722222222222285,123.44444444444444,5.4722222222222285C123.05555555555554,-1.1388888888888857,125,-10.666666666666664,118.58333333333333,-10.666666666666664C114.88888888888889,-10.666666666666664,113.13888888888889,-7.55555555555555,113.13888888888889,-1.5277777777777715C113.13888888888889,-1.5277777777777715,113.13888888888889,24.91666666666667,113.13888888888889,24.91666666666667C113.13888888888889,30.94444444444445,114.88888888888889,34.05555555555556,118.58333333333333,34.05555555555556C125,34.05555555555556,123.44444444444444,24.138888888888893,123.63888888888889,17.138888888888893C123.63888888888889,17.138888888888893,135.69444444444443,17.138888888888893,135.69444444444443,17.138888888888893C136.27777777777777,32.111111111111114,132.77777777777777,43.19444444444445,118.58333333333333,43.583333333333336C118.58333333333333,43.583333333333336,118.58333333333333,43.583333333333336,118.58333333333333,43.583333333333336" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0072,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667C151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,151.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777,151.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777C151.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777,163.91666666666666,-19.02777777777777,163.91666666666666,-19.02777777777777C163.91666666666666,-19.02777777777777,163.91666666666666,6.055555555555557,163.91666666666666,6.055555555555557C163.91666666666666,6.055555555555557,172.86111111111111,6.055555555555557,172.86111111111111,6.055555555555557C172.86111111111111,6.055555555555557,172.86111111111111,-19.02777777777777,172.86111111111111,-19.02777777777777C172.86111111111111,-19.02777777777777,185.30555555555554,-19.02777777777777,185.30555555555554,-19.02777777777777C185.30555555555554,-19.02777777777777,185.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,185.30555555555554,42.41666666666667C185.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,172.86111111111111,42.41666666666667,172.86111111111111,42.41666666666667C172.86111111111111,42.41666666666667,172.86111111111111,15.000000000000004,172.86111111111111,15.000000000000004C172.86111111111111,15.000000000000004,163.91666666666666,15.000000000000004,163.91666666666666,15.000000000000004C163.91666666666666,15.000000000000004,163.91666666666666,42.41666666666667,163.91666666666666,42.41666666666667C163.91666666666666,42.41666666666667,151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667C151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0012,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667C201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667,201.47222222222226,-19.22222222222222,201.47222222222226,-19.22222222222222C201.47222222222226,-19.22222222222222,210.41666666666669,-19.22222222222222,210.41666666666669,-19.22222222222222C210.41666666666669,-19.22222222222222,223.83333333333337,13.05555555555556,223.83333333333337,13.05555555555556C223.83333333333337,13.05555555555556,223.83333333333337,-19.22222222222222,223.83333333333337,-19.22222222222222C223.83333333333337,-19.22222222222222,234.1388888888889,-19.22222222222222,234.1388888888889,-19.22222222222222C234.1388888888889,-19.22222222222222,234.1388888888889,42.41666666666667,234.1388888888889,42.41666666666667C234.1388888888889,42.41666666666667,225.58333333333337,42.41666666666667,225.58333333333337,42.41666666666667C225.58333333333337,42.41666666666667,212.16666666666669,8.19444444444445,212.16666666666669,8.19444444444445C212.16666666666669,8.19444444444445,212.16666666666669,42.41666666666667,212.16666666666669,42.41666666666667C212.16666666666669,42.41666666666667,201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667,201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667C201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667,201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667,201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0097,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M268.5833333333333,43.583333333333336C247.97222222222223,43.583333333333336,250.5,21.611111111111114,250.69444444444443,1.5833333333333357C250.69444444444443,-12.999999999999993,256.52777777777777,-20.388888888888886,268.5833333333333,-20.388888888888886C280.6388888888889,-20.388888888888886,286.6666666666667,-12.999999999999993,286.6666666666667,1.5833333333333357C286.8611111111111,21.80555555555556,289.19444444444446,43.583333333333336,268.5833333333333,43.583333333333336C268.5833333333333,43.583333333333336,268.5833333333333,43.583333333333336,268.5833333333333,43.583333333333336M268.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664C263.9166666666667,-10.472222222222221,263.13888888888886,-6.194444444444443,263.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715C263.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715,263.13888888888886,24.91666666666667,263.13888888888886,24.91666666666667C263.13888888888886,30.94444444444445,264.88888888888886,34.05555555555556,268.5833333333333,34.05555555555556C272.27777777777777,34.05555555555556,274.22222222222223,30.94444444444445,274.22222222222223,24.91666666666667C274.22222222222223,24.91666666666667,274.22222222222223,-1.5277777777777715,274.22222222222223,-1.5277777777777715C274.22222222222223,-7.55555555555555,272.27777777777777,-10.666666666666664,268.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664C268.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664,268.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664,268.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,0.009,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667C301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,301.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777,301.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777C301.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777,313.9166666666667,-19.02777777777777,313.9166666666667,-19.02777777777777C313.9166666666667,-19.02777777777777,313.9166666666667,33.861111111111114,313.9166666666667,33.861111111111114C313.9166666666667,33.861111111111114,326.1666666666667,33.861111111111114,326.1666666666667,33.861111111111114C326.1666666666667,33.861111111111114,326.1666666666667,42.41666666666667,326.1666666666667,42.41666666666667C326.1666666666667,42.41666666666667,301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667C301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,0.0017,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M358.5833333333333,43.583333333333336C337.97222222222223,43.583333333333336,340.5,21.611111111111114,340.69444444444446,1.5833333333333357C340.69444444444446,-12.999999999999993,346.52777777777777,-20.388888888888886,358.5833333333333,-20.388888888888886C370.6388888888889,-20.388888888888886,376.6666666666667,-12.999999999999993,376.6666666666667,1.5833333333333357C376.8611111111111,21.80555555555556,379.19444444444446,43.583333333333336,358.5833333333333,43.583333333333336C358.5833333333333,43.583333333333336,358.5833333333333,43.583333333333336,358.5833333333333,43.583333333333336M358.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664C353.9166666666667,-10.472222222222221,353.13888888888886,-6.194444444444443,353.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715C353.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715,353.13888888888886,24.91666666666667,353.13888888888886,24.91666666666667C353.13888888888886,30.94444444444445,354.88888888888886,34.05555555555556,358.5833333333333,34.05555555555556C362.27777777777777,34.05555555555556,364.22222222222223,30.94444444444445,364.22222222222223,24.91666666666667C364.22222222222223,24.91666666666667,364.22222222222223,-1.5277777777777715,364.22222222222223,-1.5277777777777715C364.22222222222223,-7.55555555555555,362.27777777777777,-10.666666666666664,358.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664C358.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664,358.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664,358.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0033,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M406.25,43.583333333333336C387.5833333333333,43.19444444444445,390.88888888888886,20.44444444444445,390.69444444444446,1.5833333333333357C390.69444444444446,-12.999999999999993,396.72222222222223,-20.388888888888886,408.77777777777777,-20.388888888888886C422.3888888888889,-20.388888888888886,427.25,-10.861111111111107,426.47222222222223,3.9166666666666714C426.47222222222223,3.9166666666666714,414.4166666666667,3.9166666666666714,414.4166666666667,3.9166666666666714C414.4166666666667,-2.694444444444443,415.38888888888886,-10.472222222222221,408.77777777777777,-10.666666666666664C404.88888888888886,-10.666666666666664,403.13888888888886,-7.55555555555555,403.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715C403.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715,403.13888888888886,24.91666666666667,403.13888888888886,24.91666666666667C403.13888888888886,30.94444444444445,404.88888888888886,34.05555555555556,408.77777777777777,34.05555555555556C414.02777777777777,34.05555555555556,414.80555555555554,26.47222222222223,414.4166666666667,19.66666666666667C414.4166666666667,19.66666666666667,407.4166666666667,19.66666666666667,407.4166666666667,19.66666666666667C407.4166666666667,19.66666666666667,407.4166666666667,10.722222222222225,407.4166666666667,10.722222222222225C407.4166666666667,10.722222222222225,426.8611111111111,10.722222222222225,426.8611111111111,10.722222222222225C426.8611111111111,10.722222222222225,426.8611111111111,42.41666666666667,426.8611111111111,42.41666666666667C426.8611111111111,42.41666666666667,418.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,418.30555555555554,42.41666666666667C418.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,416.75,38.13888888888889,416.75,38.13888888888889C415,41.05555555555556,410.72222222222223,43.583333333333336,406.25,43.583333333333336C406.25,43.583333333333336,406.25,43.583333333333336,406.25,43.583333333333336" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,0.0049,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M455.27777777777777,8.000000000000007C455.27777777777777,8.000000000000007,461.5,-19.02777777777777,461.5,-19.02777777777777C461.5,-19.02777777777777,472.97222222222223,-19.02777777777777,472.97222222222223,-19.02777777777777C472.97222222222223,-19.02777777777777,461.30555555555554,22.000000000000004,461.30555555555554,22.000000000000004C461.30555555555554,22.000000000000004,461.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,461.30555555555554,42.41666666666667C461.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,449.25,42.41666666666667,449.25,42.41666666666667C449.25,42.41666666666667,449.25,22.000000000000004,449.25,22.000000000000004C449.25,22.000000000000004,437.77777777777777,-19.02777777777777,437.77777777777777,-19.02777777777777C437.77777777777777,-19.02777777777777,449.44444444444446,-19.02777777777777,449.44444444444446,-19.02777777777777C449.44444444444446,-19.02777777777777,455.27777777777777,8.000000000000007,455.27777777777777,8.000000000000007" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0043,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path><path fill="none" stroke="none" d="M0,100L1000,100" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set both padding and margins on the div? Try:

```
div {
    resize: both;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}

svg,
img {
    display: block;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried by removing all div CSS but it still not working, I tried all the possible scenario before posting here :(

Comment: Try now. I've added display: inline-block; and just removed the margins and paddings.

Comment: I tried this but still not working for me,  Can you please try in the fiddle.

Comment: The SVG WORD IS "TECHNOLOGY" BUT NOT COMPLETELY OCCUPYING THE DIV. THAT IS THE MAIN PROBLEM WE ARE FACING HERE.

Comment: Oh. I thought this was about padding and margin %]

Comment: Hmm.. Please let me help if you have the better idea here :)

Comment: Well you sat the width and height to 300px and then used viewbox to clip the svg. You see in fiddle what happens if I remove the viewbox.

Comment: Yes but not completely occupying the div without any padding and margin. If you look in fiddle there is top, bottom & right padding exists.

Comment: Hmm yes I am trying but not achieving the perfect result.

Comment: Something like viewBox="6 45 209 205". The alternative is to edit the SVG itself.

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically occupy the DIV by given any SVG?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by setting viewBox="6 45 209 205".

Is there any way to dynamically occupy the DIV by given any SVG?

Comment: Tried setting width and height on the svg to 100%?

Comment: Works for me, if you remove the div padding etc.

Comment: If its still not working, I would clarify what you are expecting to see, and whats missing. How far are you expecting the bars to come accross etc. Should there be a gap on the right hand side. http://jsfiddle.net/78cpD/72/ is  filling it for me, but I suspect that maybe not quite what you mean.

Comment: I'm expecting that any text ex."iiiiiiiiii"  within SVG should fit in the given div.

Comment: I suspect you're confusing the issue, and it has nothing to do with a div at all, and a separate issue. If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/78cpD/74/ does that work ? That's it without a div.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the extra space in the SVG, then you need to fix your SVG viewBox. Read up on how viewBox works. It's values need to correspond to the bounding dimensions of the paths in your SVG.  At the moment you just seem to have a arbitrary viewBox of "0 0 100 100".

If you actually measure it, the bounds of all the paths in your SVG are:

```
x:      0
y:      44.61
width:  1000
height: 64.36
```

So your viewBox needs to be

```
viewBox="0 44.61 1000 64.36"
```

If you plug that in you get the whole of the text. However it is tiny and centred in the 300 by 300 pixel box you have specified for your SVG `width` and `height`.

To fix that, just remove the `height` attribute.  The SVG will be scaled to fit the 300px width and the height of the SVG will be automatically calculated by the browser (using the aspect ratio implied by the viewBox).

```css
div {
    resize: both;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    padding: 1em;
}

svg,
img {
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Embedded SVG:
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" viewBox="0 44.61 1000 64.36" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.2.0</desc>
    <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs>
    <path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667C25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667,25.305555555555557,-9.888888888888886,25.305555555555557,-9.888888888888886C25.305555555555557,-9.888888888888886,16.166666666666668,-9.888888888888886,16.166666666666668,-9.888888888888886C16.166666666666668,-9.888888888888886,16.166666666666668,-19.02777777777777,16.166666666666668,-19.02777777777777C16.166666666666668,-19.02777777777777,46.5,-19.02777777777777,46.5,-19.02777777777777C46.5,-19.02777777777777,46.5,-9.888888888888886,46.5,-9.888888888888886C46.5,-9.888888888888886,37.75,-9.888888888888886,37.75,-9.888888888888886C37.75,-9.888888888888886,37.75,42.41666666666667,37.75,42.41666666666667C37.75,42.41666666666667,25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667,25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667C25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667,25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667,25.305555555555557,42.41666666666667" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.003,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;">
    </path><path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667C61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667,61.47222222222222,-19.02777777777777,61.47222222222222,-19.02777777777777C61.47222222222222,-19.02777777777777,87.13888888888889,-19.02777777777777,87.13888888888889,-19.02777777777777C87.13888888888889,-19.02777777777777,87.13888888888889,-10.472222222222221,87.13888888888889,-10.472222222222221C87.13888888888889,-10.472222222222221,73.91666666666667,-10.472222222222221,73.91666666666667,-10.472222222222221C73.91666666666667,-10.472222222222221,73.91666666666667,6.250000000000007,73.91666666666667,6.250000000000007C73.91666666666667,6.250000000000007,83.25,6.250000000000007,83.25,6.250000000000007C83.25,6.250000000000007,83.25,15.000000000000004,83.25,15.000000000000004C83.25,15.000000000000004,73.91666666666667,15.000000000000004,73.91666666666667,15.000000000000004C73.91666666666667,15.000000000000004,73.91666666666667,33.861111111111114,73.91666666666667,33.861111111111114C73.91666666666667,33.861111111111114,87.13888888888889,33.861111111111114,87.13888888888889,33.861111111111114C87.13888888888889,33.861111111111114,87.13888888888889,42.41666666666667,87.13888888888889,42.41666666666667C87.13888888888889,42.41666666666667,61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667,61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667C61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667,61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667,61.47222222222222,42.41666666666667" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0013,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path>
    <path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M118.58333333333333,43.583333333333336C97.97222222222221,43.97222222222223,100.5,21.80555555555556,100.69444444444444,1.5833333333333357C100.69444444444444,-12.999999999999993,106.72222222222221,-20.388888888888886,118.58333333333333,-20.388888888888886C132.58333333333331,-20.388888888888886,136.66666666666666,-9.888888888888886,135.69444444444443,5.4722222222222285C135.69444444444443,5.4722222222222285,123.44444444444444,5.4722222222222285,123.44444444444444,5.4722222222222285C123.05555555555554,-1.1388888888888857,125,-10.666666666666664,118.58333333333333,-10.666666666666664C114.88888888888889,-10.666666666666664,113.13888888888889,-7.55555555555555,113.13888888888889,-1.5277777777777715C113.13888888888889,-1.5277777777777715,113.13888888888889,24.91666666666667,113.13888888888889,24.91666666666667C113.13888888888889,30.94444444444445,114.88888888888889,34.05555555555556,118.58333333333333,34.05555555555556C125,34.05555555555556,123.44444444444444,24.138888888888893,123.63888888888889,17.138888888888893C123.63888888888889,17.138888888888893,135.69444444444443,17.138888888888893,135.69444444444443,17.138888888888893C136.27777777777777,32.111111111111114,132.77777777777777,43.19444444444445,118.58333333333333,43.583333333333336C118.58333333333333,43.583333333333336,118.58333333333333,43.583333333333336,118.58333333333333,43.583333333333336" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0072,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path>
    <path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667C151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,151.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777,151.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777C151.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777,163.91666666666666,-19.02777777777777,163.91666666666666,-19.02777777777777C163.91666666666666,-19.02777777777777,163.91666666666666,6.055555555555557,163.91666666666666,6.055555555555557C163.91666666666666,6.055555555555557,172.86111111111111,6.055555555555557,172.86111111111111,6.055555555555557C172.86111111111111,6.055555555555557,172.86111111111111,-19.02777777777777,172.86111111111111,-19.02777777777777C172.86111111111111,-19.02777777777777,185.30555555555554,-19.02777777777777,185.30555555555554,-19.02777777777777C185.30555555555554,-19.02777777777777,185.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,185.30555555555554,42.41666666666667C185.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,172.86111111111111,42.41666666666667,172.86111111111111,42.41666666666667C172.86111111111111,42.41666666666667,172.86111111111111,15.000000000000004,172.86111111111111,15.000000000000004C172.86111111111111,15.000000000000004,163.91666666666666,15.000000000000004,163.91666666666666,15.000000000000004C163.91666666666666,15.000000000000004,163.91666666666666,42.41666666666667,163.91666666666666,42.41666666666667C163.91666666666666,42.41666666666667,151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667C151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,151.47222222222223,42.41666666666667" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0012,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path>
    <path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667C201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667,201.47222222222226,-19.22222222222222,201.47222222222226,-19.22222222222222C201.47222222222226,-19.22222222222222,210.41666666666669,-19.22222222222222,210.41666666666669,-19.22222222222222C210.41666666666669,-19.22222222222222,223.83333333333337,13.05555555555556,223.83333333333337,13.05555555555556C223.83333333333337,13.05555555555556,223.83333333333337,-19.22222222222222,223.83333333333337,-19.22222222222222C223.83333333333337,-19.22222222222222,234.1388888888889,-19.22222222222222,234.1388888888889,-19.22222222222222C234.1388888888889,-19.22222222222222,234.1388888888889,42.41666666666667,234.1388888888889,42.41666666666667C234.1388888888889,42.41666666666667,225.58333333333337,42.41666666666667,225.58333333333337,42.41666666666667C225.58333333333337,42.41666666666667,212.16666666666669,8.19444444444445,212.16666666666669,8.19444444444445C212.16666666666669,8.19444444444445,212.16666666666669,42.41666666666667,212.16666666666669,42.41666666666667C212.16666666666669,42.41666666666667,201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667,201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667C201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667,201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667,201.47222222222226,42.41666666666667" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0097,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path>
    <path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M268.5833333333333,43.583333333333336C247.97222222222223,43.583333333333336,250.5,21.611111111111114,250.69444444444443,1.5833333333333357C250.69444444444443,-12.999999999999993,256.52777777777777,-20.388888888888886,268.5833333333333,-20.388888888888886C280.6388888888889,-20.388888888888886,286.6666666666667,-12.999999999999993,286.6666666666667,1.5833333333333357C286.8611111111111,21.80555555555556,289.19444444444446,43.583333333333336,268.5833333333333,43.583333333333336C268.5833333333333,43.583333333333336,268.5833333333333,43.583333333333336,268.5833333333333,43.583333333333336M268.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664C263.9166666666667,-10.472222222222221,263.13888888888886,-6.194444444444443,263.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715C263.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715,263.13888888888886,24.91666666666667,263.13888888888886,24.91666666666667C263.13888888888886,30.94444444444445,264.88888888888886,34.05555555555556,268.5833333333333,34.05555555555556C272.27777777777777,34.05555555555556,274.22222222222223,30.94444444444445,274.22222222222223,24.91666666666667C274.22222222222223,24.91666666666667,274.22222222222223,-1.5277777777777715,274.22222222222223,-1.5277777777777715C274.22222222222223,-7.55555555555555,272.27777777777777,-10.666666666666664,268.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664C268.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664,268.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664,268.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,0.009,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path>
    <path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667C301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,301.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777,301.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777C301.47222222222223,-19.02777777777777,313.9166666666667,-19.02777777777777,313.9166666666667,-19.02777777777777C313.9166666666667,-19.02777777777777,313.9166666666667,33.861111111111114,313.9166666666667,33.861111111111114C313.9166666666667,33.861111111111114,326.1666666666667,33.861111111111114,326.1666666666667,33.861111111111114C326.1666666666667,33.861111111111114,326.1666666666667,42.41666666666667,326.1666666666667,42.41666666666667C326.1666666666667,42.41666666666667,301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667C301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667,301.47222222222223,42.41666666666667" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,0.0017,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path>
    <path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M358.5833333333333,43.583333333333336C337.97222222222223,43.583333333333336,340.5,21.611111111111114,340.69444444444446,1.5833333333333357C340.69444444444446,-12.999999999999993,346.52777777777777,-20.388888888888886,358.5833333333333,-20.388888888888886C370.6388888888889,-20.388888888888886,376.6666666666667,-12.999999999999993,376.6666666666667,1.5833333333333357C376.8611111111111,21.80555555555556,379.19444444444446,43.583333333333336,358.5833333333333,43.583333333333336C358.5833333333333,43.583333333333336,358.5833333333333,43.583333333333336,358.5833333333333,43.583333333333336M358.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664C353.9166666666667,-10.472222222222221,353.13888888888886,-6.194444444444443,353.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715C353.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715,353.13888888888886,24.91666666666667,353.13888888888886,24.91666666666667C353.13888888888886,30.94444444444445,354.88888888888886,34.05555555555556,358.5833333333333,34.05555555555556C362.27777777777777,34.05555555555556,364.22222222222223,30.94444444444445,364.22222222222223,24.91666666666667C364.22222222222223,24.91666666666667,364.22222222222223,-1.5277777777777715,364.22222222222223,-1.5277777777777715C364.22222222222223,-7.55555555555555,362.27777777777777,-10.666666666666664,358.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664C358.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664,358.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664,358.5833333333333,-10.666666666666664" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0033,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path>
    <path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M406.25,43.583333333333336C387.5833333333333,43.19444444444445,390.88888888888886,20.44444444444445,390.69444444444446,1.5833333333333357C390.69444444444446,-12.999999999999993,396.72222222222223,-20.388888888888886,408.77777777777777,-20.388888888888886C422.3888888888889,-20.388888888888886,427.25,-10.861111111111107,426.47222222222223,3.9166666666666714C426.47222222222223,3.9166666666666714,414.4166666666667,3.9166666666666714,414.4166666666667,3.9166666666666714C414.4166666666667,-2.694444444444443,415.38888888888886,-10.472222222222221,408.77777777777777,-10.666666666666664C404.88888888888886,-10.666666666666664,403.13888888888886,-7.55555555555555,403.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715C403.13888888888886,-1.5277777777777715,403.13888888888886,24.91666666666667,403.13888888888886,24.91666666666667C403.13888888888886,30.94444444444445,404.88888888888886,34.05555555555556,408.77777777777777,34.05555555555556C414.02777777777777,34.05555555555556,414.80555555555554,26.47222222222223,414.4166666666667,19.66666666666667C414.4166666666667,19.66666666666667,407.4166666666667,19.66666666666667,407.4166666666667,19.66666666666667C407.4166666666667,19.66666666666667,407.4166666666667,10.722222222222225,407.4166666666667,10.722222222222225C407.4166666666667,10.722222222222225,426.8611111111111,10.722222222222225,426.8611111111111,10.722222222222225C426.8611111111111,10.722222222222225,426.8611111111111,42.41666666666667,426.8611111111111,42.41666666666667C426.8611111111111,42.41666666666667,418.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,418.30555555555554,42.41666666666667C418.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,416.75,38.13888888888889,416.75,38.13888888888889C415,41.05555555555556,410.72222222222223,43.583333333333336,406.25,43.583333333333336C406.25,43.583333333333336,406.25,43.583333333333336,406.25,43.583333333333336" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,0.0049,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path>
    <path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M455.27777777777777,8.000000000000007C455.27777777777777,8.000000000000007,461.5,-19.02777777777777,461.5,-19.02777777777777C461.5,-19.02777777777777,472.97222222222223,-19.02777777777777,472.97222222222223,-19.02777777777777C472.97222222222223,-19.02777777777777,461.30555555555554,22.000000000000004,461.30555555555554,22.000000000000004C461.30555555555554,22.000000000000004,461.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,461.30555555555554,42.41666666666667C461.30555555555554,42.41666666666667,449.25,42.41666666666667,449.25,42.41666666666667C449.25,42.41666666666667,449.25,22.000000000000004,449.25,22.000000000000004C449.25,22.000000000000004,437.77777777777777,-19.02777777777777,437.77777777777777,-19.02777777777777C437.77777777777777,-19.02777777777777,449.44444444444446,-19.02777777777777,449.44444444444446,-19.02777777777777C449.44444444444446,-19.02777777777777,455.27777777777777,8.000000000000007,455.27777777777777,8.000000000000007" transform="matrix(0.45,0,0,1,-0.0043,65)" stroke-width="5" font-weight="bold" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;"></path>
    <path fill="none" stroke="none" d="M0,100L1000,100" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

If you are wondering why there is so much space to the right of "TECHNOLOGY", it is because the last path in your SVG is a long horizontal line from x=0 to x=1000. That is the reason the viewBox has a width of 1000.